# Sometimes cannot connect via SSH to to GCP VM for a certain amount of time

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, terraform, openssh, terraform-provider-gcp

I am setting up a project with Terraform and Google Compute. In this project I start up multiple VMs and configure them directly afterwards via SSH. Sometimes there is a single or multiple VMs to which I cannot connect via SSH with my usual account. The problem magically disappears after approximately 5 minutes, even if I do not do anything. After this time everything works normally again. I am however able to SSH into the instance with the web interface during the down time.

I am not able to reliably reproduce this issue. It just magically happens sometimes to a random amount of VMs for about 5 minutes.

I am pretty lost on this and would really appreciate any pointer as to where I might find a solution.

Here is a short summary of the problem:

- Cannot connect to GCP VM via SSH with predefined user
- Only happens sometimes (Issue is not reliably reproducable)
- Only lasts for a few minutes (~5 minutes)
- During this time I can SSH into the VM via GCPs web interface

This is the Terraform code I am using to start the instances:

module.google:

```
variable "project"{}
variable "credentials"{}
variable "count"{default = 1}
variable "name_machine"{}
variable "zone"{}

provider "google" {
    credentials = "${var.credentials}"
    project     = "${var.project}"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "vm" {

    count = "${var.count}"
    zone = "${var.zone}"
    name = "${var.name_machine}${count.index}"
    machine_type = "n1-standard-1"

    boot_disk {
        initialize_params {
            image = "ubuntu-os-cloud/ubuntu-1604-lts"
        }
    }

    network_interface {
        network = "default"
        access_config {
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT** The code I use to SSH into the instance.

```
resource "null_resource" "node"{

    provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline="${data.template_file.start_up_script.rendered}"
    }

    connection {
        user = "${var.ssh_user}"
        host = "${var.ip_address}"
        type = "ssh"
        private_key="${var.ssh_private_key}"
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2** Terraform Output

```
null_resource.node (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
null_resource.node (remote-exec):   Host: xx.xx.xx.xx
null_resource.node (remote-exec):   User: Nopx
null_resource.node (remote-exec):   Password: false
null_resource.node (remote-exec):   Private key: true
null_resource.node (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: false
null_resource.node:   Still creating... (10s elapsed)
null_resource.node (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
null_resource.node (remote-exec):   Host: xx.xx.xx.xx
null_resource.node (remote-exec):   User: Nopx
null_resource.node (remote-exec):   Password: false
null_resource.node (remote-exec):   Private key: true
null_resource.node (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: false
null_resource.node (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
null_resource.node (remote-exec):   Host: xx.xx.xx.xx
null_resource.node (remote-exec):   User: Nopx
null_resource.node (remote-exec):   Password: false
null_resource.node (remote-exec):   Private key: true
null_resource.node (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: false
null_resource.node:   Still creating... (20s elapsed)
null_resource.node (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
null_resource.node (remote-exec):   Host: xx.xx.xx.xx
null_resource.node (remote-exec):   User: Nopx
null_resource.node (remote-exec):   Password: false
null_resource.node (remote-exec):   Private key: true
null_resource.node (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: false
...
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show how you are SSHing into the instances. Are you doing this outside of Terraform or are you using some form of Terraform provisioner? It doesn't answer your question but is there a reason you have to SSH into the instance to configure them instead of using something like Packer to create an image that is already configured?

Comment: I am SSHing both with and without Terraform. Both do not work. The content of the VMs should be dynamic, so a static image won't do. However I did not properly think through that possibility so thank you for the heads up.

Comment: Can you show how you are using Terraform to SSH in? The remote-exec provisioner already waits for SSH to be ready.

Comment: Why are you using a `null_resource` to do the provisioning instead of adding the provisioner to the `google_compute_instance` resource? Normally you would only do this if you had some form of extra dependency that needed to be fulfilled in between VM creation and provisioning occurring (such as attaching a disk). It looks to me like Terraform has no obvious dependency available to it that shows it needs to wait for the GCE instance to actually be created before trying to SSH into it.

Comment: The reason is that I have to reuse the same provisioner elsewhere in the code. However I believe this is not the problem, since I cannot even SSH into the instance manually once it is up and running.

Comment: The point is the remote-exec provisioner should already wait for the instance to be up and able to connect to it. What output do you get from Terraform?

Comment: Since there is an issue with Terraform that makes it hard to depend modules on each other ([Issue 14432](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/14432)) I am applying these two parts in separate stages. I just added what the output looks like.